# keras, invalid predict size

Tags: python, keras

im quite new in keras
I have trained this with (100,8) size of input and output,  i want to 1*8 output with 1*8 predict data.
for example
input that i enter 1*8.
code returns, 1*8 output data.

here is my code:

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation 
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
import numpy as np

xs=np.ones((100,8))
ys=np.ones((100,8))

for i in range(100):
    xs[i]*=np.random.randint(30, size=8)  
    ys[i]=xs[i]*2

xs=xs.reshape(1,100,8)   
ys=ys.reshape(1,100,8)   
# model = tf.keras.Sequential([layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[2,4])])
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Dense(10,input_shape=[100,8])) 


model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))
model.add(Dense(10)) 
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
# model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(8)) 

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'] )

model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=1000, batch_size=100)

p= np.array([[1,3,4,5,9,2,3,4]]).reshape(1,1,8)

print(model.predict(p))
```

Comment: Please read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to add one dimension in the first position of your data. for 2D network, you simply have to feed your model with data in the format (n_sample, n_features)

here the complete example

```
xs=np.ones((100,8))
ys=np.ones((100,8))

for i in range(100):
    xs[i]*=np.random.randint(30, size=8)  
    ys[i]=xs[i]*2

xs=xs.reshape(100,8)   
ys=ys.reshape(100,8)   

model = Sequential() 
model.add(Dense(10,input_shape=(8,))) 
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))
model.add(Dense(10)) 
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(Dense(8)) 

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=10, batch_size=100)

p = np.array([[1,3,4,5,9,2,3,4]]) # (1, 8)

pred = model.predict(p)

print(pred)
print(pred.shape) # (1, 8)
```

Comment: thanks its really works. but i have 2 question  1- what" input_shape=(8,)" means? 2- why do i have to do last dense 8?

Comment: input_shape=(8,) means you are passing as input a 2d array with 8 features. last dense is 8 because your target is a 2d array with 8 columns